# Cross browser audio to canvas visualisation

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api, soundmanager2

I'm working on a project of visualising audio into canvas, so far I understood that I would have to use AudioAPI, something like SoundManager 2 etc. which has a flash fallback. There is one thing tho, I don't wan't to use flash fallbacks (at the moment I would only want this visualisation to work in modern browsers with support of HTML5 audio), therefore I'm not sure if I should use it. Is it possible to achieve cross browser visualisation without any external resources? or using SoundManager 2, but somehow without flash fall back? I'm new to this, could you please outline steps that I need to take in order to proceed with project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. No cross-browser way to do this if you don't want a Flash fallback. Chrome and Safari have the Web Audio API and Firefox has the Audio Data API (for now, it's been deprecated), but IE doesn't currently have any way to manipulate audio without plugins.

Comment: I'd note that Mozilla is currently actively working on implementing the Web Audio API in Firefox, but yeah - there's no cross-browser way to do this without plugins.